# Isn't it stupid to use checkboxes as radios?

Tags: html, checkbox, radio-button, user-friendly

I have seen a lot of survey web-pages (among others) that uses checkboxes (multi-selection) as radios (one selection only). The reason they do so is that in their code they have a variable that decides how many selections in one question that can be made. If this is set to 1, it simply limits it to 1 selection instead of using the radio input. I can see the reason for this code-wise. But whenever I see a checkbox I immediately think that I can pick more than one option, however I can not.

*Basically my question is:*
Shouldn't you, when creating a survey where you use checkboxes to limit the maximum number of pickable options use radios when only one option is pickable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you *should*.  But that won't be enough characters to answer the question.